# `builtin_interfaces` package location

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Migration-Guide), in ROS2

> the types duration and time which were builtin types in ROS 1 have been replaced with normal message definitions and must be used from the builtin_interfaces package

Where are the normal message definitions? I looked [here](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/tree/ardent) and did not find a `builtin_interfaces` package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280000/%60builtin_interfaces%60-package-location/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/tree/master/builtin_interfaces

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-01-16**:
Very annoyingly, doing a Google search for "builtin_interfaces" (with quotes) does not result in this repo.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-01-16**:
I think it might be because it was moved not so long ago, SEO is still catching up. I added a link to it in the meantime: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Migration-Guide/_compare/2c4a2a35b690b2ffa44217c376b34d7ec366746d...747c5bf84aea700d7f5207301782d881a825dc20